# Xpra html5 with Ubuntu 14 server

Tags: html, ubuntu-14.04, x11-forwarding

I installed `xpra` on Ubuntu server and when I use it to bind to an address and opean an app using:

> xpra start --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:10000 --html=on --start-child=xterm

I get this error:

> xpra: error: no such option: --html

Can I use xpra html with `ubuntu 14` server?

If yes, please let me know the solution to this problem. `Xforwarding` is enabled.

If there is a need to update version , can you please tell me how to do that?
Please

Thanks
Sheenam

Answer (score 1):

The version you have installed is too old, try [xpra.org downloads](https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Download)

Comment: I think this is a comment more than an answer. Also you have enough reputation to add a comment!

Comment: @Gourav nope, this is the exact answer needed for this question. Comes up regularly through other channels too.

Comment: OK but length matters. Here it seems only like a comment the answer must be understandable even without the link if it is broken.

Comment: The link has not been broken in 10 years, and if someone doesn't understand a download link, what are they doing on SO?

Comment: I'm telling you just for precaution.